# KIVY: Image in Button is stretched

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am using the background_normal for setting image to a button, but the result is that the image is stretched.

```
Button:
        background_normal:'this.jpg'
```

Is there a way to have a center aligned image inside the button. Also please tell me how we'd do it in python.

Answer (score 2):

It's stetched because the height and the width of your button are not equal, try this

**.py**:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class NewButton(Button):
    pass
    #but if you want to set the image of the button remove the pass and uncomment the following:
    #image_path = StringProperty('')

    #def __init__(self,image_path, **kwargs):
        #super(NewButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.image_path = image_path
```

**.kv**:

```
<NewButton>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: (40,40) # choose a value of a which fit the most with your button
            pos: (self.pos[0]+self.size[0]/2.0) - 20, (self.pos[1]+self.size[1]/2.0) - 20
            source: root.image_path
    on_press: self.background_color = (1,1,1,1)
    on_release: self.background_color = (0,0,0,0)
```

Notice how I put the brackets to define the class NewButton on the kv

**update**:

```
<NewButton>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: (a,b) # choose a value of a which fit the most with your button
            pos: (self.pos[0]+self.size[0]/2.0) - a/2.0, (self.pos[1]+self.size[1]/2.0) - b/2.0
            source: root.image_path
    on_press: self.background_color = (1,1,1,1)
    on_release: self.background_color = (0,0,0,0)
```

please look the `size` and the `pos` on the canvas choose a value of `a` and `b` then set `size` and `pos`

Comment: would you tell me how can we do this using python ?

Comment: all you can do in the **.py** is define a new class for this kind of button and then in the **.kv** and then set the view of this button. I will edit my answer for it

Comment: so now i will pass my image location to background_normal or image_path ?

Comment: image_path, you don't need no more to set the background_normal

Comment: im trying that but the button shows no image. This is how im doing:
 `mg = NewButton(image_path='Pictures/1.png' `

Comment: have you put the <NewButton> code in your **kv** ? also what size have you choose ?

Comment: i have passed `size(200,20)`

Comment: I've edited my code please start with (40,40) then increase or decrease

Comment: it works but now the image does not stay in center on the button and its quite offcenter when i try something like size: (80,60)

Answer (score 0):

To do this in python, and also using just size_hints and no absolute sizes, try this:

```
class ImageButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ImageButton,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.border = (0,0,0,0)

    def on_size(self,*args):
        yhint = int(bool(self.size_hint_y))
        self.size[1-yhint] = self.size[yhint]

self.button = ImageButton(size_hint=(.1,None),pos_hint={'x':0.85,'y':.05},\
background_normal=yourbuttonimage)
```

in other words, specify the size_hint in the one dimension, and the absolute size calculated at do_layout() is copied to the other by the on_size() callback. Setting the border attribute to 0,0,0,0 is also a helpful default when working with small button images.